# Open email app from my app in listview Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to open the email app from my application and get an error.

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

The problem is, I set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
I'm also tried to **addFlags**

**This is my code:**

```
 private void mailTo(String mail) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{mail});
    try {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**I must note that, in the same class I have more working Intent Actions.**

```
private void callTo(String number) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

**And:**

```
private void smsTo(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: before I saw ur post I find that answer in other place,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone told me **Intent.createChooser** is not coping the flags.

So I needed to follows **Intent tmp = Intent.createChooser...** and re-set the flag on tmp.

**I replaced :**

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

**To:**

```
Intent tmp = Intent.createChooser(i, "").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(tmp);
```

**And removed:**

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try calling the `startActivity()` without getting it from the `context()` object? `context()` has the current state of the application, so you might not be sure from where you are starting the intent. So it would be:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

And with that, remove the flag

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

**EDIT**

Since you are calling the `intent()` from an `Activity()` that is not the `MainActivity()`, try passing the `context()` parameter to the constructor of your class.

```
Context context;

public MyAdapaterClass(Context context) {
this.context=context;
}
```

And then initiate the `intent()` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer. this class extends from BaseAdapter, so the context I get from the parent.

Comment: Somehow I understood that you were calling the Intent from the MainActivity class, I'll posted my changes.

Comment: As I said I get the context from the perent already. about the intent exmple, Its not what I need. I need Intent for Intent.ACTION_SEND.